# How to change DataView number of row items and image text alignment

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4

I have the following dataview and would like to display as many icons as can fit in a row.
However, only one icon is displayed per row. What can I do to change this behavior?

Also - How can I center the text below the image?

```
Ext.define('EMS.view.application.IconView', {
extend: 'Ext.view.View',
alias: 'widget.application.IconView',

xtype: 'iconView',
itemId: 'iconView',

layout: 'fit',

tpl: ['<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class="dataview">',
        '<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;margin:15px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
          '<img src="{src}" />',
          '{text}',
        '</div>',
    '</div>',
'</tpl>'],
itemSelector: 'div.dataview',
store: 'application.Icon',

initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set styles for .dataview as below

```
.dataview {
  width:100px; height:100px; margin:15px;
  display: inline-block; float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

and change your tpl to

```
tpl: [
     '<div style="clear:both">',
         '<tpl for=".">',
             '<div class="dataview">',
               '<img src="{src}" /><br/>',
               '{text}',
             '</div>',
         '</tpl>',
      '</div>'
     ],
```